# Getting http 500 backend error when posting to Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API to put messages into a Google Apps email account.  I use
the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol with a service account.  This is more or
less working fine.  One of our customers has asked us to put messages
directly into a Google Vault.  I don't see a Vault API, but I did find this
information related to the "insert" method (which is what we use to add
messages to a normal account):

parameter "deleted" (boolean):  Mark the email as permanently deleted
(not TRASH) and only visible in Google Apps Vault to a Vault administrator.
Only used for Google Apps for Work accounts.

When I do this, some messages are accepted, but frequently I get http error
500 in response to the POST.  The error text says "Backend Error".  I thought
the pattern was that the first time the message was posted, it would work,
but the second time would generate the error.  Therefore I was thinking it
was a duplicate check issue.  However I now see some examples of messages
that fail immediately.  The POST url looks like this:

> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/user@domain.com/messages?uploadType=multipart&internalDateSource=dateHeader&deleted=true&access_token=ABC...

As I mentioned, the same message to the same url (without deleted=true) will
always work.  Any ideas what is causing the error?

Comment: Do you have the almost all-encompassing `https://mail.google.com/` in your scopes? :) I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Yes that is one of the scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Was just fighting this issue myself.  Apparently the error has something to do if the message is compatible with the Google vault retention policies:

If I turn on a default policy of "Retain everything" then I've been able to get the messages to import correctly.  HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the import api method and the backendError seems to be related to filters/policies. For example we asked Google to reject messages with xls and macros and we get the error on mail with that kind of attachment